# Bubble sort Algorithm implementations

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

### Problem Description

Just now I am learning C++ programming language and I decide to do it by writing code. I try to write an algorithm which will sort an items in the array beginning form `min` value to `max` value to do that I get an array of integers like this

```
    int arrayToSort[] = {3,5,3,1,8,7,2,4};
```

and try to write an algorithm which will sort this array. Below you can see source code

#### Algorithm I

```
int arrayToSort[] = {3,5,3,1,8,7,2,4};
int arrayToSortSize = sizeof(arrayToSort)/sizeof(int);

for(int i=1; i<arrayToSortSize; ++i) {
    int* first = arrayToSort;
    int* end = arrayToSort + arrayToSortSize;

    for(first; first!=end-i; ++first) {
        if (*first > *(first+1)) {
            int temp = *first;
            *first = *(first+1);
            *(first+1) = temp;
        }   
    }
}
```

This Algorithm works correct and sort all elements in the array right `1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8` but I want to know ***is this algorithm right to do such sorting, I mean is this the shortest way to sort all elements in this case ?***

#### Algorithm II

Here I implement same algorithm but this time I use arrays instead of pointers, you can see source code below:

```
int arrayToSortSize = sizeof(arrayToSort)/sizeof(int);

for(int i=1; i<arrayToSortSize; ++i) {
    int* first = arrayToSort;
    int* end = arrayToSort + arrayToSortSize;

    for(int j=0; j<arrayToSortSize-i; j++) {
        if (arrayToSort[j] > arrayToSort[j+1]) {
            int temp = arrayToSort[j];
            arrayToSort[j] = arrayToSort[j+1];
            arrayToSort[j+1] = temp;
        }   
    }
}
```

This algorithm works well too. It sort all items correctly, but I want to know ***which algorithm is better to use, and may be which one is faster (if one of them is) ?***

### Questions

- Which of the algorithms is better to use ?
- Which algorithm is faster ? Or they work in a same speed ?
- Is ***Algorithm I*** or ***Algorithm II*** can be implemented in the better way ?
- How this algorithms called ?

[image: Sorting example image]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_sorting_algorithms#Comparison_of_algorithms

Comment: [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth thanks a lot grate help !!!

Comment: If you want a fast sorting algorithm then you should have a look at Quicksort. If your array is "nearly" sorted, you should probably use Insertion Sort as it works slightly faster on nearly sorted arrays than Quicksort.

Comment: @Smartfox: You've written two (slow) implementations of "bubblesort", which is a slow sort to begin with.  I'd recommend doing more research before worrying about which of your implementations is fastest.  (BTW, they should be identical or nearly so in speed)

Comment: Slightly off topic, but std::set will sort automatically as you insert: std::set:insert and you're done.

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks for help, two (slow) implementations of "bubblesort", is there a fast implementation of "bubblesort" ?

Comment: @Smartfox Bubble Sort is a slow algorithm itself. There is no fast implementation of a slow algorithm.

Comment: Looks like people are not reading Knuth anymore...

Comment: @AliAlamiri: Its possible to write a bubblesort about twice as fast as what you have, but even that is considered too slow to ever be used in real code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two "algorithms" are two implementations of the same algorithm called *Bubble sort*.

This is the most simple algorithm to do sorting but performs poorly (quadratic complexity).

If you want to dig deeper into sorting algorithms, there are great books for that, I particularly like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020172684X).

If you just want to look at algorithms that perform faster, take a look at `quicksort` or `mergesort`. They both have advantages and drawbacks, but you can usually choose one of them depending on your application and the size of your data.

More generally, prefer `std::sort` which does a great job at tayloring the particular algorithm needed depending on the size of your data when relevant and possible. Only if you see you have performances issues (or for learning purposes), you can look at implementing your own `sort`. But you really gotta know what you're doing because it is easy to write bad-performing sort implementation (even for a good algorithm).

**Edit (precision)**: In real life, when the array is small enough (say, less than 20 items), go with `insertion sort`. Otherwise, go with `quicksort` if you do not have more hypotheses about your data. The reason for this cutoff is that the cost of recursive calls can account for too much a overhead on small amount of data than just using a quick `insertion sort`.

Answer (score 0):

Neither.

The differences between using arrays and pointers is negligable in most cases.

Both Algorithm I and II are what is called a bubble sort. It is an effective sort in some cases, but is rarely the fastest sort.

Comment: It's effective in some cases?  I believe in virtually every case it's slower than insertion sort.

Comment: @MooningDuck What if you don't have extra storage to keep 2 copies of your data around? Perhaps because you are executing on an embeded platform with minimal local storage. Remember time is not always the limiting factor.

Comment: sorry, got my naming wrong, inisertion sort is in place so does not need 2x storage. however it does work and I will not discount that there may be cases where it is the best choice (but very very few)

Comment: I don't disagree that it works, and I won't claim it has no use-case, but I simply can't think of a case where it's the best.

Answer (score 0):

Both the algorithms find the bigger value, then the second etc...
so if you have N elements first run of the loop will compare N-1 element, second line in the loop will compate N-2 etc..

It called bubble sort.
It take approximation of (N-1)N / 2 compare operation.
If you use quick-sort (for example) which is binary search you will need O(N log N) operation which is critical for large number of N.
[Quicksort from wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

Comment: Careful, worst case complexity for Quicksort is quadratic (sorted array). It's `O(N log N)` only on average.